# Tools for drawing weather-rose-overlays on maps/locations

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, mapping, visualisation, user-interface

I need to create a map with points-of-interest. My initial idea is to "build" wind-roses using KML file and Openlayers: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html.

This seem a bit labor intensive, so I wonder if anyone has any good alternative suggestions for this. Tools, programming language, etc. all is open.

The points-of-interests shall have an transparent overlay of a wind rose when selected.

WindRose example:

[image]

Comment: Looks very interesting (in fact I'm now wondering if I could incorporate such a cool rendering into point maps!) - could you describe your dataset? XY point, with fields for values at compass direction?

Comment: You could probably generate a custom canvas icon style in OpenLayers from the POI's data.  Take a look at the source code for https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.chart.html to see how it could be done.

Comment: You could use free (chart.js, example: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/polar.html) or commercial (KOOLCHART, example: https://www.koolchart.com/demo/windrose-chart) JS library to draw diagram in HTML element, and display it on OL map with `ol.Overlay` layer.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS you could render something like the graphic you show using the geometry generator marker option.

[image]
[image]

Each cardinal direction could have a field associated with it - N, NE, E, etc.

Each triangle would be built using the coordinates ($x, $y) of the point and rotated depending on the compass direction:

```
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(0 + pi()/16) * "E"*100, $y + sin(0 + pi()/16) * "E"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(0 - pi()/16) * "E"*100, $y + sin(0 - pi()/16) * "E"*100))
```

All the triangles would need to be collected into a single geometry. Generated very inefficiently in this example as below - better to define a custom function that just takes direction / distance and passes it to make_triangle, but here goes:

```
collect_geometries(
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(0 + pi()/16) * "E"*100, $y + sin(0 + pi()/16) * "E"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(0 - pi()/16) * "E"*100, $y + sin(0 - pi()/16) * "E"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "NE"*100, $y + sin(pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "NE"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "NE"*100, $y + sin(pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "NE"*100)),    
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi()/2 + pi()/16) * "N"*100, $y + sin(pi()/2 + pi()/16) * "N"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi()/2 - pi()/16) * "N"*100, $y + sin(pi()/2 - pi()/16) * "N"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(3*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "NW"*100, $y + sin(3*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "NW"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(3*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "NW"*100, $y + sin(3*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "NW"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi() + pi()/16) * "W"*100, $y + sin(pi() + pi()/16) * "W"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(pi() - pi()/16) * "W"*100, $y + sin(pi() - pi()/16) * "W"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(5*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "SW"*100, $y + sin(5*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "SW"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(5*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "SW"*100, $y + sin(5*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "SW"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(6*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "S"*100, $y + sin(6*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "S"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(6*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "S"*100, $y + sin(6*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "S"*100)),
make_triangle( 
    make_point($x, $y), 
    make_point($x + cos(7*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "SE"*100, $y + sin(7*pi()/4 + pi()/16) * "SE"*100), 
    make_point($x + cos(7*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "SE"*100, $y + sin(7*pi()/4 - pi()/16) * "SE"*100))   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Macromedia Freehand - if the year was 1999. Thats what i used when i was at University, to do a very similar project.

Jokes aside though, the point im making is that perhaps this is less of a 'GIS Software' question and maybe more of a 'multimedia software' question?

You could potentially create the windmills in said multimedia software and then ave them as .png's. Then bring them in as linked popups when selecting the points of interest on the map.

Alternatively, the windmill type graphs are essentially an adaptation of a pie chart. This might help when choosing your software, as most GIS software can produce pie charts. Might need some tweaking to produce the 'windmill effect'.. (Set null values to blank or transparent or similar).